# Is it possible to display a line diagram as a transparent clickthrough drawing overlay?

Tags: software-recommendation, xfce, image-viewers

After dozens of pair programming session over zoom I have fallen in love with their annotation feature.

My usecase is, we sketch the function we are implementing on the screen (flow chart, block diagram etc.) and then type the corresponding code.

For my solo programming sessions, I am searching for an equivalent native Linux tool which can

1. Take my UML diagrams and
2. Project it as a line diagram with transparent clickthrough background...

Does such a tool exist in Linux?